# Hidden div appearing and backgrounditems dissapear/unvisable

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

My project is a content based Website for my mother and her Children-daycare.
You can see the project on the domain: [Diekleinenfreun.de](http://www.diekleinenfreun.de)

Now, as you see on the Website I have the navbar on the left.
And what I did is I used a simple javasyriptcode to make a div set to display:block; on mouseOver and none when mouseOut again.
I want to fill the div with content later. as a preview or an image or so.

My problem with this div is the alignment. As you can already see on the Page login, the div in making problems with any other content in the middle.
I first had the div set to relativ, wich solves the problem if the browserwindow's size is changed, but it pushes all other items in the middle down obviosly.

So what I need is this div not changing any other item in the middle, but rather blurring them out and laying over them if you understand what i mean.

The code I use:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
//-->
</script>

<a href="http://www.diekleinenfreun.de/?plid=2"><center><input onMouseOver="toggle_visibility('login');" onMouseOut="toggle_visibility('login');" type="button" class="nav_login" value="Login" /></center></a>

<div id='login' class='login_middle'>a</div>

.login_middle {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 760px;
  height: 70%;
  top:243px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  font: normal 16px/1 Georgia, serif;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  text-align: center;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: rgba(18,50,145,0.85);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ;
  display:none;
}
```

Or the original CSS class, which messes with the items in the middle, but is resized automaticly:

```
.login_middle {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 760px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relativ;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  font: normal 16px/1 Georgia, serif;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  text-align: center;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: rgba(18,50,145,0.85);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ;
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: The intended behaviour seems to be unclear. So you have default content on the page, but if the user hovers a menu item, an additional element should cover the original content and show something else?

Comment: Yes, a div box should cover it and not mess with the positions of the original content

Comment: Right now, your site features a table-based layout (which is not the best option anyways) and all the content divs for your menu items are inside the middle column. By hovering a menu item, one of these content divs is shown while the others are hidden. I don't see a problem right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question, you are having an issue with the middle container (it's located inside a TD in your website) when it's resized.

To stop that just remove `width: 760px;` from the .login_middle{...} and other css classes such as .home_middle{ ...}, etc. or you could set `width: 100%;`.

To fix the issue of content pushing to the bottom, change/add css as below.

```
.table_mid{
  ....
  position: relative;
}
```

and every css class you use for middle content for example, kontakt_middle
(according to your .kontakt_middle class at the time of writing, just set the position attribute)

```
.kontakt_middle{
  .....
  position: absolute;
}
```

Also, I noticed in other css classes you used; for example, .links_middle{} - remove top attribute and set height to 100% as you have already done to .kontakt_middle{}.

I hope this helps.

Comment: not only the TD is resized, the content of the TD is pushed under the Div, thats the main problem

Comment: What is the browser, it's version and OS you are using? I cannot generate that issue from my end.

Comment: I use Chrome and im on Windows 10 64bit. But try clicking on login, there is already some content and the problem i mean you see if you hover over the button "Kontakt"   -> The div is pushing the content down

Comment: Ok, I managed to generate the issue. I will add the solution for it in to my answer above.

Comment: As you can see now, i changed it like you said. it dows work, but the size of the div is the whole screen now   EDIT: Nevermind, my mistake, i mispelled relative. THANK ALL OF YOU ALOT!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it would be much better if you stuck to conventional web design practice, and used a separate .html page for each page of content, instead of doing this Javascript mouseover as you are.

You could easily transform this layout into a responsive three column design template, which you could use for each page of your site.  Doing it this way, your site can be displayed nicely on mobile, which is now important.  As it is, display on mobile is not looking good.

Rgds

Comment: The actual content for each site will be a different html page or outsorced, but what i want is just a div over the content that is shown right now while hovering ofer the navbar